Localize Pdftron strings in UWP app not working in debug mode
I have localized my UWP app and for paper related items I am using pdftron library.We have added a German translation to the pdftron library.


The localized items are not getting translated when a release is built. But it works in debug mode or when run through release mode from visual studio.How can I fix this

This sounds like it falls under "default resources", so this might help. Some  takeaways include:

You set your app's default language in the Default language field on
the Application tab in your app package manifest source file
(Package.appxmanifest).
To confirm that your overridden defaults are being taken into account,
look for the file \obj<ReleaseConfiguration
folder>\priconfig.xml and confirm that its contents match your
overrides.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/app-resources/specify-default-resources-installed
